# Any idea how to extend vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php

Tags: magento2

Need help if there is a way to extend "vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php" in order not to touch the core file while waiting for Magento 2 fix the issue.

Thanks,
JM

Comment: What is the purpose of override this file?

Comment: Nevermind @SukumarGorai. I figured out the issue on my end. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how you managed this?